# What does this part of code do in the java stream class?

Tags: java, stream

I am trying to learn Java. I have a small piece of code trying to read and write input streams. But there is one line that I just don't understand the meaning.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this part :?

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
```

What does variable `C` actually do?

How does the program really function?

Does the variable `C` read from the input stream file and after it has read, the part which is being read it's cleaned and eliminated from the input stream file?

Would anybody please assist me by explaining what this code generally does line by line?

Comment: To be more explicit, you've asked 6 questions, some of which have acceptable answers. You need to "accept" answers that provide a solution by clicking the checkmark at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29):

> Returns:
>
> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

Meaning that this:

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
```

Means that until the input stream has not found the end of file, that is, there are still characters in the file, keep reading. Once that you have read the next byte of data, write it to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are used when you need to read from and write into the file respectively in the form of `bytes`....

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
 }
```

**-** What you are doing is that, you are **reading the data** in the file `xanadu.txt` in the form of bytes and then **writing it to file** `outagain.txt`.

**-** And it will continue till `in.read()` returns `-1`, as **-1 will indicate the EOF** (end of file).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the meaning of this part :?

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
```

Reads byte by byte from `xanadu.txt` file and output it to `outagain.txt` also byte by byte.

> What does variable C actually do?

Java is case-sensitive, so it `c` not `C`. It has the value of byte read from input file.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);}
```

In the above code as per the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) the method `in.read()` **returns -1** if it reaches the **end of the file** so what it means is that you need to stay in the loop untill the read method does not return -1

**How does the program really function?**

Now coming to this part 
you are basically reading the file as rawbytes using `FileInputStream` and writing it as a file again using `FileOutputStream` where the above while loop determines you write the whole file till the end

**Does the variable C read from the input stream file and after it has read, the part which is being read it's cleaned and eliminated from the input stream file?**

The method `read()` Reads a byte of data from the input stream and returns it so you have to write the data simultaneously as you read and yes the previous byte that has been read would be removed as it reads a new byte

**FileInputStream** is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as **Image** data. For reading streams of characters, consider using **FileReader**